# How can I calculate all cross-terms in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I would like to calculate all cross-terms of each vector in a matrix.
For example, consider the following matrix:

```
X = tensor([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]]),
```

and I would like to obtain all cross-terms of each vector in this matrix as:

```
Y = [[1*1, 1*2, 1*3, 2*2, 2*3, 3*3],
     [4*4, 4*5, 4*6, 5*5, 5*6, 6*6]].
  = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9],
     [16, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]].
```

That is, this is the all combination values of the vector elements
and I believe that this can be calculated using torch.combinations;
however, torch.combinations does not provide the batch implementation
and I couldn't produce the above result in pytorch.

How can I calculate all cross-terms in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the product of combinations with replacement for each of the rows in that matrix

```
>>> torch.stack(tuple(torch.prod(torch.combinations(data[i],with_replacement=True),1) for i in range(data.shape[0])),0)
>>> tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  9],
        [16, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and your code will work but uses the for loop for tensor data. I would like to process tensor data as a batch, but torch.combination is not a batch-based implementation. Is this a difficult implementation?

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/40375